# Need help understanding this Python Code

Tags: python

This Code below:

```
def increment(n):
    return n+1

def square(n):
    return n**2

def findSequence(initial,goal):
    candidates = [(str(initial), initial)]
    for i in range(1, goal - initial + 1):
        newCandidates = []
    for (action, result) in candidates:
        for (a,r) in [(' increment',increment),(' square',square)]:
            newCandidates.append((action+a,r(result)))
            print (newCandidates)


findSequence(1,2)
```

Outputs:

```
[('1 increment', 2)]
[('1 increment', 2), ('1 square', 1)]
```

I understand this part: 
[('1 increment', 2), ('1 square', 1)]

but what about this:
 [('1 increment', 2)] part?

or why the [('1 increment', 2)] part is two times also when I write:

```
newCandidates[0]
```

I get [('1 increment', 2)] but when I write newCandidates[0] I get out of bounds error and never get [('1 increment', 2), ('1 square', 1)]  as output.

Comment: the for loop which creates new candidates is not needed it will just create an empty list

Comment: the goal parameter has not effect on the function apart from causing errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to have the objective to display in a list of tuples, the results of an increment and power operation, for the initial value up to the goal value.
It seems to me the code is not correct, because it outputs only the result for the initial value. Here is the code if you want to print the values for all the range between initial and goal:

```
def increment(n):
    return n+1


def square(n):
    return n**2


def find_sequence(initial,goal):
    candidates = []
    for i in range(initial,goal):
        candidates.append((str(i), i))
    newCandidates = []
    for (action, result) in candidates:
        for (a,r) in [(' increment',increment),(' square',square)]:
            newCandidates.append((action+a,r(result)))
            print (newCandidates)


find_sequence(1,3)
```

Also, it print one element duplicated because the print is made on the for designated for the list of operations. If you outdent one level the print (as in below), it will not duplicate:

```
def increment(n):
    return n+1


def square(n):
    return n**2


def find_sequence(initial,goal):
    candidates = []
    for i in range(initial,goal):
        candidates.append((str(i), i))
    newCandidates = []
    for (action, result) in candidates:
        for (a,r) in [(' increment',increment),(' square',square)]:
            newCandidates.append((action+a,r(result)))

        print (newCandidates)


find_sequence(1,3)
```

Comment: I am very sorry. Actually, I was quite disturbed (and hadn't slept well for long) at the moment and overlooked a very simple thing. The append function. Sorry for this nuisance post.

Comment: No problem, my friend ;). Please, do not forget to award the points, after you get some sleep, of course.

Answer (score 0):

This code print's the following lines when called with parameter's initial and goal

```
 [(initial +" increment",intitail+1)]
 [(initial +" increment",intitail+1),(initial +" square",intitail**2)]
```

It has no purpose other than to give this output
and the real question is what do you want the output to be?